# Volume Control while Playing Muliple File Using nAudio

Tags: c#, naudio

I have an application which needs to play multiple audio files using nAudio but I want to mute any one when I want to. I set the Volume property of the instance of the WaveOut i want to Zero.

```
myWaveOut.Volume=0;
```

The problem is when I do that all the audio out of that application mutes. Even thou all the audio uses its own instance of WaveOut.

Why is this happening, and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WaveOut.Volume property sets the device volume. To set the stream volume, insert a VolumeSampleProvider into your signal chain, or more simply just use the AudioFileReader class which has a Volume property.

Answer (score 1):

Separate audio channels volume is adjusted in other way than the main volume. There is quite related [discussion on NAudio codeplex page](https://naudio.codeplex.com/discussions/443454).